# Notice: Array to string conversion In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-enterprise, magento-1

```
if (false !== ($data = Mage::app()->getCache()->load($_lessCacheId))) {
                $_oldLessConfig = unserialize($data);   
                if (count(array_diff_assoc($_oldLessConfig,$_newLessConfig)) == 0 && count(array_diff_assoc($_newLessConfig,$_oldLessConfig)) == 0) {
                    $_hasChange = 0; 
                }
                else{
                    $_hasChange = 1;                
                    Mage::app()->getCache()->remove($_lessCacheId);
                    Mage::app()->getCache()->save(serialize($_newLessConfig), $_lessCacheId, array('EM0131_LESS_CSS_CACHE'), 86400);        
                }
            }`
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `unserialize` method call.

This method only accepts a string as a parameter and your `$data` variable is an array.

Double check the content of that variable and modify your code to ensure your unserialize the string you want

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Cache_Core::load() already has unserialize() call in it. You do not need to unserialize data in you code one more time.

```
/**
 * Test if a cache is available for the given id and (if yes) return it (false else)
 *
 * @param  string  $id                     Cache id
 * @param  boolean $doNotTestCacheValidity If set to true, the cache validity won't be tested
 * @param  boolean $doNotUnserialize       Do not serialize (even if automatic_serialization is true) => for internal use
 * @return mixed|false Cached datas
 */
public function load($id, $doNotTestCacheValidity = false, $doNotUnserialize = false)
{
    if (!$this->_options['caching']) {
        return false;
    }
    $id = $this->_id($id); // cache id may need prefix
    $this->_lastId = $id;
    $this->_validateIdOrTag($id);

    $this->_log("Zend_Cache_Core: load item '{$id}'", 7);
    $data = $this->_backend->load($id, $doNotTestCacheValidity);
    if ($data===false) {
        // no cache available
        return false;
    }
    if ((!$doNotUnserialize) && $this->_options['automatic_serialization']) {
        // we need to unserialize before sending the result
        return unserialize($data);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

So in your case $data contains array instead of the string.